# Do Titans have a weak point?

Tags: titanfall

In *Titanfall*, do the different Titans have weak points that are better to shoot at? If so, are they the same on the different chassis?

Comment: Yes they do have weak spots. But only with certain weapons and only an shield down. Then they flash video game weak spot red.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the red areas on Titans mean?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163621/what-do-the-red-areas-on-titans-mean)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate of that question, unless you knew about the glowing red areas on Titans beforehand and just didn't mention it.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro It's still appropriate to mark it as a duplicate, because the answer is the same, and this way, this question can serve as a useful signpost that will direct users to the information they're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do have weak points... but hitting them at their weak points will deal extra damage *only* if their shields are depleted.

[The titan's weak spots will be highlighted red when their shields are depleted.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163621/what-do-the-red-areas-on-titans-mean)  Each titan is different so naturally the red weak points on each of the titans will be on different locations.

---

Then of course, there is the option to jump onto a titan as a pilot to rodeo and attack them directly bypassing their shields.  Of course, take caution going this route because you will be left very vulnerable when attacking a titan this way.  [There are ways to defend against rodeoing pilots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160027/what-can-i-do-to-stop-an-enemy-pilot-from-rodeoing-my-titan) so look out when attacking a titan this way.